# how publish power bi report server dashboards in a public site?

Tags: power-bi-report-server

Is there a way to publish the dashboards in the **Power BI report server** on the public site without the need to use the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Publishing Power-BI report is fairly possible ([Dashboards are not supported in PBIRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/compare-report-server-service)), as long as you can expose the local web-server (SSRS) to public network the PBI dashboard type of reports can be accessible as public site.

Unfortunately, every user must go through [supported authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15#authentication-types) by SSRS, fundamentally Power-BI Report server follows the same authentication methods that are supported in SSRS.